# Como usar o rowCount para limitar o número de registros num banco de dados postgresSQL usando o node js?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, back-end

Estou usando o script para fazer isso, mas me aparece o erro internal server error. Alguem sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
var sqlQtd = db.query(`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM segunda`, function(err, result){
    return result.rowCount;
});

if(sqlQtd >= 44){
    return res.send("O HORARIO ESTÁ CHEIO");
}
```

Comment: Qual lib está utilizando para acessar o banco de dados?

Comment: Estou usando o postgreSQL com o Pool

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar o comportamento desejado, vc pode fazer o seguinte fluxo:

```
exports.countElements = (req, res, next) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM segunda';
    postgres.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'Houve um erro'}] });
        }
        if (result.rows.length >= 44) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ location: req.path, msg: 'O HORARIO ESTÁ CHEIO'}] });
        }
        //...fazer suas coisas...
        next();
    });
};
```

Em meu exemplo utilizei o padrão de retorno `json`, mas pode retornar os valores da maneira que já está fazendo.

Se precisar de mais exemplos, basta postar aqui.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá! obrigado pela resposta. Eu usei o script que voce mas parece que ele está ignorando a condição e está cadastrando no banco mesmo assim

Comment: Você não postou o código do cadastro. essa validação deve estar antes do cadastro. Além do mais em meu exemplo utilizei o retorno como json, no seu vc envia um `send()`

Comment: O código do cadastro vc se refere ao código onde eu uso o INSERT INTO para inserir os registros no banco?

Comment: Sim. Corretamente.

Comment: Ela está sendo usada antes, o codigo da inserção é esse

// colocar valores dentro do banco de dados
 const query = `INSERT INTO segunda("nome", "cpfSegunda")
         VALUES ($1, $2)`

 const values = [nome, cpfSegunda];

 db.query(query, values, function(err){
  //fluxo de erro
  if(err){
   //cont04 = cont04-1;
   return res.send("Erro no banco de dados. Talvez o CPF já tenha sido cadadstrado.")
  } 
  //fluxo ideal
  return res.redirect("/CultoSegunda");
 });

Comment: Pois é, você mesmo já falou que está sendo usada depois, o correto é verificar a quantidade antes de fazer a inserção. Você pode editar a sua pergunta para adicionar as informações adicionais.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que você faça uso de módulos para facilitar a sua vida trabalhando com nodejs, e procure um package para postgree que trabalhe com `promises`.

Suponhamos que você tenha um arquivo chamado `DB.js` feito no seguinte modo:

```
module.exports = {
   limite: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.query(`SELECT COUNT (*) FROM segunda`, function(err, result){
         if(err)
            return reject(err);

         return resolve(result.rowCount);
      })
   })
};
```

Podemos prosseguir em diversas maneiras, mas a mais fácil seria controlar tal limite na route que você precisa, então se você tiver algo como:

```
const DB = require('DB.js');
app.post('insert/registro', async (req, res) => {
   try{
      const limite = await DB.limite();
      
      if(limite > MEU_LIMITE_AQUI)
        throw Error('Limite maximo atingido');

      // Daqui em diante só inserir o teu código de insert...
   } catch(e){
      res.status(413); // Forbidden status header
      res.send({ error:'O HORARIO ESTÁ CHEIO' });
   }
});
```

Se você precisa implementar este controle em mais rotas, você pode adicionar a resposta do Danizavtz e usar este controle como um `middleware`, ficaria algo como:

```
const controller = require('MODULO CRIADO NA RESPOSTA DO Danizavtz');
app.post('insert/registro', controller, (req, res) => {
   // aqui dentro você pode fazer o insert sem precisar fazer nenhum controle
});
```